# After using [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations], the next animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

The problem is when I'm using:

```
[transLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

(transLabel is a `UILabel` that show the information)

After that, I try to add a new animation to this Label

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:showTime
             animations:^{
                 transLabel.hidden = NO;
                 transLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    transLabel.hidden = YES;
                    transLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}];
```

But It didn't work anymore, it just work at odd number click. Like, first time it works, and second time it doesn't work, but third time it shows again, forth not, fifth yes..

What I want to do is keep pushing down one button again again again
and the Label is show again again again with animation

Thank you and wait for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, the problem occurs because the presentation layer do all the animations and are the layer that actually performs all the animations. When you cancel an ongoing animation that is reflected upon the presentation layer and not the view layer. Try capturing the changes to the view's layer and see if that helps you in this case:

```
transLabel.layer.transform = transLabel.layer.presentationLayer.transform;
```

Comment: Would you mind to telling me this code is adding to where? After or before the removeAllAnimations? Or putting in completion?

Comment: Before. But it seems the original problem still exists. Why do you even want to remove the animations during runtime and not let it complete? They will stack up and run when they are done.

Comment: Because my app suppose to do is, show the label and user touch the screen for the item that label describe, after user find that item and touch it correct, the label would change and show another word.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue. The problem is that when you stop animation you hide your transLabel.

Show it right after [transLabel.layer removeAllAnimations]; like this:

```
[transLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
transLabel.hidden = NO;
```